# Setting AWS S3 CORS that files could be fetch only from website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I have a website where all files are stored in AWS S3 and client want that some private files couldn't be accessed only when having file link.

Is it possible to somehow set CORS or something else that if I copy image link, which is stored in S3, and paste it into browser it would be denied, but if browser requests that image for displaying in the website it would be ok?

Answer (score 0):

Use cloudfront,  here the official [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)